# Change radio button 'checked' attribute on form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I've got two radio buttons. Which a user can select and submit dynamically to change the content of a HTML table I have.

How can I use jQuery to set the 'checked' attribute to the appropriate radio button. So, United Kingdom is checked by default and thus filled in 'blue'. When a user clicks Wales the radio button that is checked will be Wales and not United Kingdom.

This also needs to be reversible (i.e. selected UK after selecting Wales).

Here is my code:

```
<input type="radio" name="region" value="0" checked="checked" /> United Kingdom 
<input type="radio" name="region" value="1" /> Wales
```

And my current Javascript which just submits the form:

```
$('input[name=region]').change(function(){
                    $('form').submit();
                });
```

Please note that the `form` submits to the same webpage as that's where my HTML `<table>` is located.

Comment: Isn't the functionality you described the default `radio` behavior?

Comment: When the page submits and thus loads `index.php` again the `html` generates again. So it generates the same `input` tags and thus United Kingdom remains checked.

Comment: You should save the selection somewhere (cookie, database, etc) and then instead of auto checking United Kingdom, first get your data and depending on your data, check either UK or Wales

Answer (score 1):

see this code i hope it works.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('input[name=region]').change(function(){
        alert(this.value);
                $('form').submit();
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if your form is method="POST" you need php:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['region']) && $_POST['region'] == 1)) { echo 'checked="true"'; } ?>
```

or if its method="GET"

you can and set it with jQuery using getting parameter from url (example: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/get-url-parameters-using-jquery.html )

if

```
var param = 'your value of region param'
```

then do

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="region"][value="' + param + '"]')[0].checked = true; 
});
```